# Validate chosen plugin dropdown using jquery validate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-chosen

I made dropdown using chosen plugin and want to validate uisng jquery validate_init.js plugin but i cant validate

I give both rules and messages in validate.js file but cant  work for 
  me,find my code below

```
<select class="chzn-select form-control input-crtl input-drp" id="cus_record" name="customer_name" placeholder="Select Customer" width="391px">
  <option value="0">Select Customer</option>
  <?php foreach($customers_records as $key=>$value) { ?>
    <option <?php if(set_value('customer_name',$this->form_data->customer_id) == $value->id) { echo "selected";} ?> value="<?php echo $value->id; ?>"><?php echo $value->first_name." ".$value->last_name."(".$value->email.")"; ?></option>
   <?php } ?>
 </select>
```

```js
$("#advertisement_form1").validate({
  rules: {
    customer_name: {
      required: true,
    }
  }
  customer_name: {
    required: 'Customer name field is required.',
  },
})
```

Comment: Check the console for errors

Comment: @Rory McCrossan console does not give me any error

Comment: So nothing happens at all? Are you sure the `#advertisement_form1` element exists?

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan yess

Comment: Then unfortunately we can't really help you as there's not enough information here to debug any problems.